# Why server unexpectedly closed network connection?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, putty, tunnel

I'm using a public key on the server and a private key on my local for authentication. Also I access databases on my server through tunneling.

But sadly when I leave that connection alone for about 1 min, that connection will be closed. Why? How can I make it alive forever *(until I close it)*?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> In your session properties, go to Connection and under Sending of null packets to keep session active, set Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off) to e.g. 300 (5 minutes).

Source: https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/

Comment: Thanks to the link you provided, I cannot connect to my server anymore https://superuser.com/questions/1249225/how-can-i-keep-ssh-connection-alive

Comment: If you are struggling with the server side config of sshd, you could try an alternative like [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh).  Here are some instructions for [windows clients](http://tutorialspots.com/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-on-windows-by-using-autossh-2984.html)